# Creating a variable inside a for loop but accessing it outside the loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, scope, global-variables, createelement

When creating elements using a loop and adding a class to them, should I first declare the variable outside the loop?

For example:

```
const mainContainer = document.queryselector('.main-container');

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach((num)=> {
 const newEl = document.createElement('div');
 newEl.innerHtml = num;
 mainContainer.appendChild(newEl);
 newEl.addEventListener('click',()=> {
  window.open('google.com')
 })
})
```

This would open 5 new tabs, but the only way I can access the element is inside the loop, should I delare newEl outside the loop and just change it with let?

Comment: What would the purpose of declaring it outside be?

Comment: I don't see why not...

Answer (score 0):

If you want references to the elements you've created, you can do:

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const newEls = [1,2,3,4,5].map(num=> {
  const newEl = document.createElement('div');
  newEl.innerHtml = num;
  mainContainer.appendChild(newEl);
  newEl.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    window.open('google.com')
  });
  return newEl;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside the loop you are calling a function. By default, the function has its scope killed as soon as the function exits/pops, which means the variable will be unset when the function exits and you won't be able to access it outside the function (or even loop).

For your code, there were some errors which have been rectified:

const mainContainer = document.queryselector('.main-container');

```js
const mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container')[0];

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach((num)=> {
 const newEl = document.createElement('div');
 newEl.innerText = num;
 mainContainer.appendChild(newEl);
 console.log(mainContainer);
 newEl.addEventListener('click',()=> {
  window.open('google.com')
 })
})
```

```html
<div class="main-container"></div>
```